# How to exclude all sub-folders in the directory using fileset?

Tags: jenkins, ant, fileset

I have an ANTScript like:

```
<fileset dir="${sqlDirectory}" >
    <include name="**/*.sql"/>
    <exclude name="**/back_out/**"/>
</fileset>
```

I am trying to exclude all sub-folders in the directory. The above code excludes only `back_out` subfolder.

Is it possible to exclude any sub-folders inside the directory?

Comment: Please don't put solutions in your questions. If you've found an answer, post it *as an answer* below, so you can mark it accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution which I have found:

```
<fileset dir="${sqlDirectory}" >
    <include name="**/*.sql"/>
    <exclude name="*/**/*" />
</fileset>
```